# A regression manhwa where female lead is to be married to someone but betrayed by her brother

Tags: story-identification, manga

I once saw a recommendation wherein the title has a word “lie” in it but it’s not *You’re Eternal Lie* I think the female lead has also blonde hair and the male lead has dark hair. I also remembered that she was to be married to male lead but her brother betrayed her due to jealousy. I guess she was more powerful than her brother that’s why he is jealous. I remembered both leads were in a carriage going to the male lead’s place but female lead was assassinated by her brother. She then regressed to a time where she thought her brother was only concerned for her that’s why he keeps on advising her to just live a low-key life and now when she returns back in time she realizes it was only because he only do it for his own benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like ***[My Sweet Enemy, Thy Name is Husband](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-sweet-enemy-thy-name-is-husband)***.

> Canach Riadon — a slave who rose to emperor and the man I wed in my first life. Yet our ill-fated marriage left my family murdered and my homeland destroyed at his hands. Now given a second chance, I vow to succeed in this political marriage and save all I love... Or will his love save me first?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe this and explain how it matches?